# Change Target Value button to change color for each button from value comparison

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change button background color based on change in target value. 
Initially i set a target value such as "10", when i click my "1" button and change it to "9". Therefore, my background color button change to "red" because input value is lesser than target value. 
However, at some point, i wanted to change my target value and trigger with "Change Target Value" button. For the trigger, it will re-compare target value with button's value, and change background color based on arithematic operator. 
Somehow, my code doesn't work. Please help.

[image]

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('button:not([id=reset]):not([id=submit])');
// target value
var TV = document.getElementById('inputtarget');
// Each button click => open modal 
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].onclick = function() {
    TV.setAttribute('startbtn', this.id);
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }
}
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function() {
    if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  //Arithematic Operator Control
function checkValue() {
  var inputvalue = document.getElementById('modal');
  var buttonsubmit = document.getElementById(TV.getAttribute('startbtn'));
  var value = parseInt(inputvalue.value);
  var targetValue = parseInt(TV.value);

  if (value < targetValue) {
    buttonsubmit.style.background = 'red';
    buttonsubmit.innerText = value;
  } else if (value >= targetValue) {
    buttonsubmit.style.background = 'green';
    buttonsubmit.innerText = value;
  } else {
    buttonsubmit.style.background = '';
    buttonsubmit.innerText = ''
  }
  modal.style.display = "none";
  return false;
}
// Change Target Value
var CTV = document.getElementById('trigger'); 
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('button:not([id=reset]):not([id=submit])');
  CTV.onclick = function() {
    for (var i = 1; i < btns.length + 1; i++){
      var btn = document.getElementById("b"+i);
        for btn.style.background = 'red' && 'green'){
          if ( btn.innerHTML<targetvalue ){
            btn.style.background='red';
          }
          else if ( btn.innerHTML>=targetvalue ){
            btn.style.background= 'green';
          }
          else
            btn.style.background= '';
        }
    }
  }
```

```css
#b1,
#b2,
#b3 {
  background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 0 1px #999;
}

#b30,
#b31 {
  background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
  height: 50px;
  width: 25px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 1px #999;
}

#inputtarget {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1;
}

#trigger {
  height: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

#b1:hover,
#b2:hover,
#b3:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

#b1:active,
#b2:active,
#b3:active {
  background-color: silver;
  box-shadow: 1px #666;
  transform: translateY(2px);
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content/Box */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
}

#modal1 {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <!-- All Buttons in Matrix Form Production -->
  <button id="b1" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:10px">1</button>
  <button id="b2" style="position:absolute; left:80px; top:10px">2</button>
  <button id="b3" style="position:absolute; left:130px; top:10px">3</button>
  <input id="inputtarget" class=numberonly value=0 type="number" min="0" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" onkeypress='return event.charCode>=48 && event.charCode<=57' ; style="position:absolute; left:55px; top:70px">
  <br>
  <input id="trigger" type=button value="Change Target Value" style="position:absolute; left:165px; top: 80px">
</div>
<!-- The Modal Box 1-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>PLEASE INPUT QUANTITY</p>
    <input id="modal" type="number" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" onkeypress='return event.charCode>=48 && event.charCode<=57' ; style=font-size:20px>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button id="submit" class=submit_on_enter onclick="return checkValue()">SUBMIT</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `for btn.style.background = 'red' && 'green'){` What is that supposed to do?  It's throwing an error.

Comment: that is for button that have background color red and green. Sometimes there are grey background, which i wanted it to be ignored. So i only wanted to "for loop" button consist of red and green background color.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me.  All the buttons are grey to start with, how do they become red or green if you only loop over buttons that are red or green?

Comment: Without the "Change Target Value" codes, the value on the button will turn red is less than target value and green if more than target value. After that i wanted to change the target value and re-compare it with buttons with background color that are "red " and "green" from previous comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just made a mistake in your for loop.  Here's the event handler part, slightly rewritten:

```
// Change Target Value
var CTV = document.getElementById('trigger'); 
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('button:not([id=reset]):not([id=submit])');

CTV.onclick = function () {
  for (var i=0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    var btn = btns[i];
    if ( btn.innerHTML<targetvalue ){
      btn.style.background='red';
    }
    else if ( btn.innerHTML>=targetvalue ){
      btn.style.background= 'green';
    }
    else {
      btn.style.background= '';
    }
  }
}
```